# Изминения значение параметра в url по нажатию на ссылку

Tags: php, ubuntu

У меня есть такая таблица:

```php
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>
        <th><a href='?sort=1&direction=1'>Название продукта</a></th>
        <th><a href='?sort=2&direction=1'>Цена в грн</a></th>
        <th><a href='?sort=3&direction=1'>Количество (кг/шт)</a></th>
        <th><a href='?sort=4&direction=1'>Стоимость в грн</a></th>
        <th>Действие</th>
      </tr>";
```

Мне нужно по нажатию на ссылку, что бы менялся параметр direction на 0 или 1.
Считать значение direction я могу, но как правильно изменить и записать его новое значение - в
этом проблема.

Comment: так получили вы `$directon = $_GET['direction'] ?? 1`, испоьзуете это значение для сортировки, а при генерации ссылки инвертируете значение `$d = $direction == 1 ? 0 : 1` и выводите его в хтмл `...&direction={$d}..`